# commit datatable changes to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server and I use the `fillschema` to get this table from SQL Server into a `DataTable` in C#. All is working ok.

I make some changes to this `DataTable` and I want to send it back to SQL Server. The fastest solution is the bulk copy but the table already exists in SQL Server.

Is there any other option to commit the changes from the `DataTable` to the SQL Server table?

Comment: Why can you not bulk copy to table that already exists?

Comment: The bulkcopy will insert the rows to that table without remove the existing data is that correct? The main think i want to do is to get the table from sql make so changes fast and commit the database back to sql. Is this possible?

Comment: Just truncate the table first to delete all existing data.

Comment: @AshleyMedway: If this specific instance of the app is NOT the only thing using that table OR the table has any type of foreign keys associated OR if you want to preserve any type of restore process using transaction logs OR if there is even the remote possibility that the bulk copy will fail then your advice would be a very very bad thing to do.

Comment: @ChrisLively I agree with you but the OP has said he wants to **remove** existing data before **inserting**. If the OP wants to do an **update** on the data rather than remove -> insert then truncate wouldn't be an option. OP could you please clarify?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @George: More info needed.  How many total records are you dealing with?  What percentage of them are likely to change prior to the commit?  What is the nature of the changes (ie: can they be handled in pure sql without moving all of that data over the network wire .. twice?)  IF you have a relatively large amount of data of which only a tiny percentage is changing then sending an update command for each relevant record is the best path.  If you are doing something like "add 1 to the quantity for ALL records" or similar than just passing a single update query is best.

Comment: If we're talking a medium to small amount of records, which requires individual processing to determine which ones are updated and which aren't, then an alternative would be to use a TVP and just pass the records to be updated into a stored proc which did a merge on the table.

Comment: Firts of all thank you everybody for your answers. The specific table has an average of 500.000 records with 15 columns and 2 indexes and one id unque. In the c# app i m getting a lot of data via tcp protocol and compare them with the data that already exist on the table so I need to have access to the datatable always and thats why i m bring it to a c# memory datatable. I'm getting about 500tcp msg per second!I now try a solution to transfer the database via bulkcopy to a temp table and MERGE the changes to the main one every one minute. It looks pretty good but do you have any better advice?